# Query regarding calculation of survival analysis

Tags: bioinformatics, theoretical-biology, statistics, biostatistics

According to [this](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/BS704_Survival/BS704_Survival_print.html) tutorial, for table to find the survival estimates, the square root of the 6th column is multiplied with the 4th column, which is Survival probability. The value that should come for the 7th column for the 2nd row is 0.052((square root of 0.003)*0.950=0.052) but in the tutorial it is given 0.049. Am I making any mistake with the calculation?

Many of the values in the table does not match with the calculations given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"0.003" is rounded up; the exact value is 1/380, which is 0.00263157894... (and some more decimal places).

If you calculate the table entries to a few more decimal places, you get 0.04873397172 (and so on), which rounds up to 0.049.